# Solutions for z^2 = x^2 + y^2 in C. Code works for small number but segfaults for bigger numbers

Tags: c

I wrote some code in python and C to find solutions for z^2 = x^2 + y^2, x, y and z being all integers. From the python code, which seems to work fine, I know how many solutions there are for some given range. For x and y ranging from 1 to 10000, there should be 14471 unique solutions, or double that, 28942 counting duplicates.

In the following code if I use the ranges from 1 to 1000 for x and y, and set the array solutions to have an appropriate size(2064 in this case) the code works fine. **But when I try extend the range of x and y to 1 to 10000, I get a segfault, but don't know why so.**

```
int main()
{
  int solutions[28942][2]={0};
  int counter = 0;

  for(int x=1;x<10000;++x)
  {
    for(int y=1; y<10000;++y)
    {
      float z = sqrt(x*x + y*y);
      if(z == (int) z) 
      {
        solutions[counter][0] = x;
        solutions[counter][1] = y;
        ++counter;
      }
    }
  }

  for(int i = 0;i<28942;++i)
  {
    printf("This is a solution: {%d,%d}\n",solutions[i][0],
                                           solutions[i][1]);
  }

  printf("value of counter is %d\n",counter );
}
```

Comment: Time for `gdb`.......

Comment: access violations are best dealt with by writing robust code: e.g. use `assert` to check your assumptions when accessing into a static array

Comment: You are exceeding the bounds of your array.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but `for(int i = 0;i<counter;++i)` would make more sense.

Comment: Your `counter` gets larger than your array bounds... Segfault happens for me (using `gdb`) when `counter = 29652` (wayyyyy out of bounds!)

Comment: Add `if (counter >= 28942) exit(1);` before `solutions[counter][0]`.

Comment: Suggest using `double z`  instead of `float z`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe your code accepts solutions that are not legit.
Comparing floats to int is a tricky business.

try doing it like this:

```
int z = (int) sqrt(x*x + y*y);

if(z*z == (x*x + y*y)) {
    solutions[counter][0] = x;
    solutions[counter][1] = y;
    ++counter;
}
```

that way you're comparing integers only

Comment: Good answer. I just tried your suggestion and now the code seems to output 28942 solutions as hoped.

Answer (score 2):

- Avoid declaring large arrays on the stack, as it may cause stack overflows. A stack overflow might manifest itself as a seg fault. `solutions` should be declared dynamically with malloc() instead.
- Never do floating point comparisons using the == operator. This is because of the inaccurate nature of floating points and nothing unique to C. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples). Instead you need to check

  ```
  if ( abs(z - (int)z) >= EPSILON)
  ```

  where EPSILON is some appropriate constant, for example 0.0001f.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, your stack is not big enough to hold nearly 60000 ints.

Try to allocate it as a global variable (in the data segment), or use dynamic memory allocation.